# Back Scholes theta of the call at any time t

Tags: greeks

I 'm trying to get the theta of a Call in the classical Black Scholes model.
We have (classical result with usual notations) :

$$C_t = S_tN(d_1) - Ke^{r(T-t)}N(d_2)$$
When deriving according to time, I get, among others terms, this one : 
$$N(d_1)*\partial{S_t}/\partial{t}$$

But I can't find anywhere this term in any formula I found on the net ...

None of the proofs I saw of the fomula 
$$ \theta_t =  - \frac{S \sigma}{2\sqrt{T-t}}N'(d_1) -rKe^{-r(T-t)}N(d_2) $$
are clear to me. Because I don't understand why $S$ is treated as if it was not time dependant ...

What do I miss ?

Comment: The term $\frac{\partial S_t}{\partial t}$ does not exist. You cannot differentiate sample paths with respect to time. The path is non-differentiable. Theta ($\Theta_t$) tells you how the option price changes if time moves a bit and everything else (including the stock price) remains constant (ceteris paribus)

Comment: @KeSchn I agree with you, this term does not exist ... but what you say "everything else (including stock price) remains constant" .. is not mentionned in the definitions I saw of the theta .. at least where I looked at .. can you send a reference (paper or somtheing else) ?

Comment: That’s how all partial derivatives are defined: keep all variables but one fixed and see how the function changes if that one variable makes an infinitesimal move. Perhaps you want to have a look at some introductory book like John Hull? He has a chapter on the Greeks.

Comment: This document gives the derivation of Theta on page 9. The only small trick is that a simplification takes place at one point by applying the identity $S_t N'(d_1)-K e^{-r(T-t)}N'(d_2)=0$. The proof of this identity is found in another question on this forum if you have never seen it before. http://www.mkaranasos.com/oldsite/FEGreeks.pdf

Comment: @noob : thank you, but your doc doesn't answer my question : why is $S_t$ considered as constant and not time (or time to maturity accordintg to your definition) dependant ? KeSchn comment gives a better answer ... But your doc gives me another question : is $\theta$ the derivative of the price according to time or to time to maturity ? What is the "**official**" definition ?

Comment: The standard definition of Theta is the derivative w.r.t. time t, see again the book by John Hull, where I get all my standard definitions. (Also I am not surprised that KeSchn knows much more than I do).